# How do I send custom data from my Android app to Google Analytics?

Tags: android, google-analytics

NOTE: I am using v2 for the android Google Analytics SDK

I have spent a good deal of time research this question. I read about custom variables, which seem to be unsupported in SDKv2. I read about custom dimensions and metrics, but the android developer page says you must first define these through the web interface, and their instructions for doing so are either outdated, wrong, or both.

All I want is to send some data in a key value pair, like:

```
sendData("questions asked", 10);
sendData("questions correct", 7);
```